# Password expiry in gatein jboss

Tags: jboss, passwords, gatein

I am now using organization api og jboss to create user.

Now I want to have set the password expiry date. Is there any way to do it by just calling api provided by jobss.

or

we should add our own logic like cron job.

Comment: Do you need to enable this on Gatein ? what version of Gatein are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use an LDAP and configure it:
http://docs.exoplatform.com/public/index.jsp?topic=%2FPLF40%2Fsec-Reference_Guide-Authentication_And_Identity-LDAP_Integration-LDAP_Default_Store.html

or if you don't have an LDAP server (or don't want to), you can implement your own logic by:

1/ Redefine the Service OrganizationAuthenticator and Implement the authenticate method

**Or**

1/ Add a new LoginModule

2/ Add in the UserProfile of each user a field holding the date of password expiration.

3/ In the authentication method, you can test on this field in addition to the username/password check.

Hope this helps you.